Thymeleaf recursive fragment fails at runtime with source is null for getProperty
I want to create a recursive template with Thymeleaf 3.1.2. (The full code is below).
I have a recursive Node class:
public static class Node {
    public String description2;
    public List<Node> children2;

    public List<Node> getChildren() {
        return children2;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description2;
    }
}   

The recursive structure is very simple and has no children:
Node root = new Node();
root.description2 = "The root";
root.children2 = List.of();

The template:
<div th:insert="~{this :: fragmentForNode(${root})}"></div>
            
<div th:fragment="fragmentForNode(node)">
    <span th:text="${node.description}"></span> 
    <ul th:if="${!node.children.isEmpty()}">
        <li th:each="child : ${node.children}">
            <div th:insert="~{this :: fragmentForNode(${child})}"></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

When I run this test, I see that getDescription is called, then getChildren, then isEmpty.
I then get the following exception which I can't explain because there is an if condition that should stop the recusion.
 org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating OGNL expression: "node.description" (template: "        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
        <head>
            <title>Help!</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div th:insert="~{this :: fragmentForNode(${root})}"></div>
            
            <div th:fragment="fragmentForNode(node)">
                <span th:text="${node.description}"></span> 
                <ul th:if="${!node.children.isEmpty()}">
                    <li th:each="child : ${node.children}">
                        <div th:insert="~{this :: fragmentForNode(${child})}"></div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </body>
        </html> 
" - line 10, col 11)
at 
...
Caused by: ognl.OgnlException: source is null for getProperty(null, "description")

After digging a bit more by creating a more complex hierarchy, I got the template working by patching with a check ${node} != null. It is like the fragment definition is also a call to the fragment.
<div th:if="${node} != null" th:fragment="fragmentForNode(node)">
    <span th:text="${node.description}"></span> 
    <ul th:if="${!node.children.isEmpty()}">
        <li th:each="child : ${node.children}">
            <div th:replace="~{this :: fragmentForNode(${child})}">
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

Here is the full code:
import java.util.List;

import org.thymeleaf.ITemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.context.Context;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.StringTemplateResolver;


public final class RecurseTest {

    
private static final String HTML = """
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
        <head>
            <title>Help!</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div th:insert="~{this :: fragmentForNode(${root})}"></div>
            
            <div th:fragment="fragmentForNode(node)">
                <span th:text="${node.description}"></span> 
                <ul th:if="${!node.children.isEmpty()}">
                    <li th:each="child : ${node.children}">
                        <div th:insert="~{this :: fragmentForNode(${child})}"></div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </body>
        </html>
""";

private static ITemplateEngine createTemplateEngine() {
    StringTemplateResolver templateResolver = new StringTemplateResolver();
    TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
    return templateEngine;
}

public static class Node {
    public String description;
    public List<Node> children;
    
    public List<Node> getChildren() {
        System.err.println(description + ".getChildren");
        return children; 
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        System.err.println(description + ".getDescription");
        return description;
    }
}   

private static Node createHierarchy() {
    
    Node root = new Node();
    root.description = "The root";
    root.children = List.of();
    return root;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Context context = new Context();
    context.setVariable("root", createHierarchy());
    String html = createTemplateEngine().process(HTML, context);
    System.err.print(html);
}
}

